# Merge renamed folders in git

Tags: git, version-control, git-merge

On the `master` branch there is a directory `dir1`. Some feature branch was outgoing from the master branch and changed some files in `dir1`.

Meanwhile in the `master`branch the directory `dir1` was renamed to `dir2`. Now I want to merge the feature branch to the `master` branch. The result should be that **both** directories should exist in the master branch.

Unfortunately *git* is unable to do so with simple commands. Since it tracks the content it tries to put the changes from the files in `dir1` to `dir2`. How to tell *git* to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd try the following before having done the merge:

```
git merge --no-commit
git checkout feature -- dir1/
git checkout master -- dir2/    
git commit
```

. With `--no-commit` you force git to create the commit automatically if there are no conflicts.